# "Popular questions" list no longer appears on any SE website

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design, hot-questions

The recent redesign changed the list on the right from "recent tags and bounties" to "popular questions on the general SE network". I liked this change because I'm far more interested in these questions than in the tags which have been used recently, and used this list frequently.

However, it appears that this specific change has been reverted, because the tags and bounties are back on the right again. Is there a reason for this change, or is this just a bug?

Comment: Looks like a caching burp.

Comment: Indeed, appears to no longer be the case.

Comment: @Oded cache needs water then. Did you give it?

Comment: @Sha - naw. Held it on my shoulder and gave it a few pats on the back till it cleared itself.

Comment: @Oded you should totally post that as a tip on http://parenting.stackexchange.com/ for those who father a young and active cache too! :P